# Why do OpenShift action hook scripts fail with strange errors?

Tags: openshift

I renamed an action_hook from a non-cartridge-specific action hook (such as `post_restart`) to be cartridge-specific (such as `post_restart_cron`) and then encountered strange new errors such as:

```
/var/lib/openshift/${USER}/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/post_restart_cron: line 5: `firstcron-secondcron': not a valid identifier
```

The script file post_restart_cron is:

```
#!/bin/bash

function firstcron-secondcron {
    echo in function
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that non-cartridge-specific action hooks apparently run bash in non-POSIX mode which allows hyphens in function names, but cartridge-specific action hooks run bash in POSIX mode which does not allow hyphens in function names.

Why do cartridge-specific action hooks run bash in POSIX mode? I'm not 100% sure, but I think the following occurs:

1. [v2_cart_model.rb:cartridge_hooks](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/bf83ed91b680635a2f874acfe892f2f51b1c762e/node/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb#L1370) remembers the hook as `source <hook filepath>`.
2. [v2_cart_model.rb:do_control_with_directory](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/bf83ed91b680635a2f874acfe892f2f51b1c762e/node/lib/openshift-origin-node/model/v2_cart_model.rb#L1270) creates a command string `set -e; <path to control script> <action> <other args>; source <hook filepath>`.
3. It probably passes that string to `sh -c` which runs in POSIX mode and because it uses `source`, it reads the script directly instead of running it in a new process (which would read the `#!/bin/bash` line and run `/bin/bash` which is by default non-POSIX mode).

There must be something different about the non-cartridge-specific codepath in `v2_cart_model.rb` that avoids the steps above.

My solution was to use `unset POSIXLY_CORRECT` in my script which disabled POSIX mode.

I debugged this issue by running the `set` command in my script which showed a variety of bash variables leading to investigations that I used the process of elimination on.